# Getting the red price listed on products on amazon through the product services api

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to get a list of products and their prices using the item_search api, that corresponds to the list of products on amazon. I am able to get a matching set of products, but am not able to consistently get the prices listed in red on the website. I am getting the price through the first offer, Offers>>Offer>>OfferListing>>Price>>FormattedPrice, and am guessing that's not the right way to get the 'red' price. Was wondering if someone could help me out.

Thanks

Comment: (For future reference, you don't need to delete the question to add/remove tags, just click 'Edit' and change the tags)

Comment: does anyone have any clue? I'm completely stumped on this one, and would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Red Price Query]

If by "red price" you mean the `$17.87` pointed to in the image above then this is the price that the product is sold at by the `MerchantId` of `Amazon.com` which is returned in the `OfferFull` response group.

To get **only** `Amazon.com` offer listings returned in the response, set the `MerchantId` request attribute to `Amazon`.  You can then use the node you've been using (`Offers > Offer > OfferListing > Price > FormattedPrice`) to consistently get the "red price".

If there are no offers returned when using the `Amazon.com` `MerchantId`, then Amazon does not have the product in stock and it's perhaps only sold by third parties.

For example, the following pseudo request will get **only** the offer listings that are sold by `Amazon.com`:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
Operation=ItemLookup&
ItemId=1451648537&
Condition=All&
ResponseGroup=OfferFull&           <- make sure you have this set to OfferFull
MerchantId=Amazon&                 <- set this one to get only Amazon.com offers
Version=2009-03-31&
Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]&
Signature=[Request Signature]
```

See the documentation for [OfferFull](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/index.html?RG_OfferFull.html) response group for more info.

Comment: not sure about this, doesn't works for me... not sure how to get this red price, also there are times when it doesn't show price at all at amazon site and there is a value for ListPrice